# locationd daemon keeps getting jetsammed ios 8.1

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the users location in an app that I'm making, but once every day or so the locationd daemon gets jetsammed because of which my app stops receiving location data.

The daemon restarts, if i bring my app or any other location aware app to the foreground, but there can be long pause before this happens

locationd's foot print is pretty small but its highwater mark is pretty low too, so looks like its pretty easy for it get into the danger zone.

The largest processes can be anything from Facebook, to DespicableMe, to Paper, to Zen Garden to my app, I have seen no real pattern here and my app isn't killed or receives a Low Memory notification when this happens

Some jetsam entries below

```
ProcessesName       |            <UUID>                |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)

locationd <bea15e205fed399c957ba05a7086271f>       759.999        6911                0         +58          8279   50      [highwater]      (daemon)

locationd <bea15e205fed399c957ba05a7086271f>      1940.653        6896                0           -          8683   50      [highwater]      (daemon)

locationd <bea15e205fed399c957ba05a7086271f>      1954.360        7155                0           -          8701   50      [highwater]      (daemon)


locationd <bea15e205fed399c957ba05a7086271f>      4612.639        6551                0           -          7743  100      [highwater]      (daemon)
```

Not sure what I can do to prevent locationd from jetsamming or what the cause might be.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using background mode with core location I recommend you use significant location update mode when in the background.  Your app will get relaunched if required in order to execute your location delegate modes.

Comment: How does it matter which mode you are in if the daemon itself has been killed.
My app is not getting killed, it's locationd which is getting killed

Comment: I must say I have never examined the log to see if locationd is alive or not...I just assume the os looks after that sort of thing - all I know is that my app keeps receiving location updates

Comment: Please could you tell me where you got that jetsam log from? I have a similar problem and seeing the high-water reason might help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

If you are using the "While Using" location permissions and for some reason locationd recycles (given enough time, any process would), the previous permissions that your app acquired while it was in the foreground are not carried forward to the new instance, that is why until you re-launch the App location updates do not resume.
This is most likely a bug.

If you use "Always" location permission then you don't run into this problem, any instance of locationd will provide you the data.